# Is there a reason why the width of the body background gradient dont always match with the margins of a div

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I want to set a body background to 30.08% cream and 69.2% gray. I am doing this with a css gradient. Then I what to have all my articles to be `margin-left: 30.08%;' to meet the line of the background (so the background line, created by the gradient is like a ruler). Here is the code

```
body{   
position: relative;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #faf4f2, #faf4f2 30.08%, #777777 30.08%, #777777);
}
article{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px; 
  background: red;
  margin-left:30.08%;

}
```

This works great, but as you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BDNR/1/) example, the article does not always align with the gradients line. So depending on the browser width, it looks sloppy in some cases. In the jsFiddle example, you are going to see the problem I have if you resize the window to `652px` (but that is not the only point) . Unfortunately this happeness at so many different points that I dont think a media query would do the job.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Why such imprecise percentages?

Comment: To be honest I can not remember the reason why the percentages are so imprecise. But I'm sure the problem would still exist in other percentage values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given your body  width and height of 100%

> When you give an element a width of 100% in CSS, you’re basically
>   saying “Make this element’s content area exactly equal to the explicit
>   width of its container — but only if its container has an explicit width.”

and then you are using

```
article{
margin-left:30.08%;
}
```

30.08% of what? 
 as said above you should use %  `only if its container (which in this case is a block level element <body>) has an explicit width.`

You can read more about it here..

[Read it here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/)

and i have changed your code a bit changing the values from % to  pixels

```
body{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #faf42, #faf42 90px, #777777 90px, #777777);

color: darker(#77777, 10%);
width:300px; height:300px;
}
```

it seems to be working now. the values are for demonstrational purpose only. change it according to your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "30.08% of what?" that is why I thought I should put 100% on the body. I removed the width and height from the body, by there is no difference

Comment: I changed the width and height in pixels and moreover changed the background gradient  a little bit and it seems to be working now. see my updated answer.

Comment: is not working for me! this is the result with your code http://jsfiddle.net/6BDNR/2/

Comment: check your fiddle again you have not written it properly you have written                                                                   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #faf42, #faf42, 90px, #777777 90px, #777777)  whereas it should be                          background : -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #faf4f2, #faf4f2 90px, #777777 90px, #777777)  error: comma before 90px and color value not writtem properly, try correcting them. and see if it works.

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zf4km/  try this if it suits you. checked in chome and firefox.

Comment: "Make this element's content area exactly equal to the explicit width of its container — but only if its container has an explicit width." <- You do not need an explicit width on an any ancestor element for `width: 100%` to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/YpSwM/

Comment: I was talking about block level element. Block level elements automatically occupy the region available and do not require explicit 100% declaration. Read the link given in the answer as i was talking in its context.